# Create local database in datagrip

Tags: sql-server, database, local, datagrip

Does anybody know how to work locally in Datagrip? For example, when you install SQL server you can just run queries and work on your DB that is stored in your PC and not in a server, is this possible in data grip?

Comment: Short answer yes.  Download SQL Server Developer and install it locally.  THen you can connect to localhost like you would a remote SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can run database in Docker container. For MS SQL Server refer to their [Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-ver15).

Additionally, [DataGrip works with LocalDB](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/10/07/connecting-datagrip-to-sql-server-express-localdb/).